# How can I require "pin shortcut" permission programmatically when I use Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I know I can use Code A to require permission in runtime.

I hope to create pin shortcut fro an app , sometimes Code B can create pin shortcut successfully in one mobile phone, but failed in another mobile phone.

I find some mobile phones need to enable "pin shortcut"  permission  manuanlly in *Setting* UI, so Code B can't create "pin shortcut"  in these mobile phones.

Can I  I require "pin shortcut"  permission programmatically ?

**Code B**

```
  fun requestPin(context: Context, resultIntent: IntentSender? = null) {

     val shortcutManager = context.getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)

      val shortcutList = shortcutManager.pinnedShortcuts

     if (shortcutList.isEmpty()) {
          if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported) {
              val pinShortcutInfo = ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, SHORTCUT_ID).build()
              shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, resultIntent)
         }
      }
   }
```

**Code A**

```
private val PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
    )
}else{
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    )
}

 private val permReqLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        permissions ->
    val granted = permissions.entries.all {
        it.value
    }
    if (granted) {
        launchMain()
    }else{
        toast(getString(R.string.permissionDenyInfo) )
        finish()
    }
}
```